# Turn a list of dataframe columns into ordered factors

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a number of (but not all) columns I want to turn into ordered factors.

My simulated data:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("level1", "level1", "level2", "level3", "level1", "level4", "level4"), 
                 var2 = c("level3", "level1", "level2", "level4", "level1", "level4", "level3"), 
                 var3 = c("level4", "level3", "level1", "level2", "level4", "level3", "level1")), 
            .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
            row.names = c(NA, 7L), 
            class = "data.frame")
```

The vector of columns to be changed is defined as follows:

```
ToFactors <- c("var1", "var2")
```

I tried the following:

```
df[ToFactors] <- factor(df[ToFactors], ordered = TRUE, 
                 levels = c("level1", "level2", "level3", "level4"))
```

However, this turn all cells into `NA`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using lapply

```
 df[, ToFactors] <- lapply(df[, ToFactors], factor, ordered = T, levels = c("level1", "level2", "level3", "level4"))
```

Answer Updated thanks @Pratik for the changes.

Comment: rather `df[, ToFactors] <- lapply(df[, ToFactors], factor, ordered = T,
                         levels = c("level1", "level2", "level3", "level4"))` for ordering factors

Comment: As @Patrik_P rightly points out, the solution by Hunaidkhan is not what I wanted because it does not order factors. Patrik_P's solution works. Not sure what the custom on SO is, but I'll accept the answer because the comment has the it right.